# Cannot View Orders

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, order-details

After upgrading to Magento 2.3.1, I can't view order.
Each time I tried to view an order I get the error,

**"Information Changes Have Been Made to this sections that have not been saved. This tab contains invalid data. Please resolve this before saving."**

Screenshot here:

[image]

Comment: Could you please open the page source by clicking on `CTRL + U` you will find the exact error

Comment: @paul It would be grateful if my answer helps you then please mark my answer correct and upvote my answer so it helps other readers who is facing similar issue. Keep coding :) thanks

Answer (score 2):

Generally this issue occur due to `Temando_Shipping` module.

Disabling `Temando_Shipping` module fixed this issue. Probably something to due with existing data on a magento instance being upgraded.

**I hope this will help**

Comment: Thanks, Muhammad. That resolved the issues. Saw that issue mentioned on Github by other developers so I hope the team will fix that.

Comment: Really nice and short answer. It solve my problem.

Comment: great working for me...

Comment: Thanks @VishalBaraiya Glad It helped you :)

Comment: But it is not working for me. Any other solution. https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/291758/information-changes-have-been-made-to-this-section-that-have-not-been-saved-thi