# Error when trying to view order in admin panel

Tags: magento2, php, admin, orders, error

When trying to click to view a particular order in the Magento 2.3.2 back-end I get a blank page with the following message:

> Order View
>
> Information Changes have been made to this section that have not been
>   saved. This tab contains invalid data. Please resolve this before
>   saving.

Screenshot here:

[image]

The source code for this page is as follows:

```
<html><head></head><body><div class="admin__page-nav" data-role="container" id="sales_order_view_tabs">
            <div class="admin__page-nav-title" data-role="title" data-ui-id="sales-order-tabs-title">
            <strong>Order View</strong>
            <span data-role="title-messages" class="admin__page-nav-title-messages"></span>
        </div>
        <ul data-ui-id="sales-order-tabs-tab-sales-order-view-tabs" class="tabs admin__page-nav-items">


            <li class="admin__page-nav-item" data-ui-id="sales-order-tabs-tab-item-order-info">
                <a href="#sales_order_view_tabs_order_info_content" id="sales_order_view_tabs_order_info" name="order_info" title="Order Information" class="admin__page-nav-link tab-item-link  " data-tab-type="" data-ui-id="sales-order-tabs-tab-link-order-info">

                   <span>Information</span>

                   <span class="admin__page-nav-item-messages" data-role="item-messages">
                       <span class="admin__page-nav-item-message _changed">
                           <span class="admin__page-nav-item-message-icon"></span>
                           <span class="admin__page-nav-item-message-tooltip">
                               Changes have been made to this section that have not been saved.                           </span>
                       </span>
                       <span class="admin__page-nav-item-message _error">
                           <span class="admin__page-nav-item-message-icon"></span>
                           <span class="admin__page-nav-item-message-tooltip">
                               This tab contains invalid data. Please resolve this before saving.                           </span>
                       </span>
                        <span class="admin__page-nav-item-message-loader">
                           <span class="spinner">
                               <span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span>
                               <span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span>
                           </span>
                       </span>
                   </span>
                </a>
                <div id="sales_order_view_tabs_order_info_content" style="display:none;" data-ui-id="sales-order-tabs-tab-content-order-info">
<div id="order-messages">
    </div>
```

Having researched this issue I have disabled the `Temando_Shipping` module as detailed in this question: [Cannot View Orders](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/269799/cannot-view-orders).

Unfortunately this has not resolved the issue.

Investigating further has revealed that this issue may be caused by string truncation as detailed here: https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/16958

But it is stated that this issue should have been fixed in a previous release.

So far this has only happened on a single order but I am concerned that there may be others if I do not fix the issue.

I should probably point out that this order contains bundle product items, I don't know if that is a cause but as it's something we're starting to use and has been mentioned in connection to a similar issue I thought I should mention it.

In addition the payment method used was a Visa Card passed through SagePay PI integration.

The following error also seems to be appearing in the Apache logs:

> AH01071: Got error 'PHP message: PHP Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call
>   to undefined method
>   Magento\Bundle\Model\Product\Type::getConfigurableAttributeCollection()
>   in
>   /var/www/vhosts/examplewebsite.com/httpdocs/vendor/magento/module-configurable-product/Helper/Product/Options/Loader.php:52\nStack
>   trace:\n#0
>   /var/www/vhosts/examplewebsite.com/httpdocs/vendor/magento/module-configurable-product/Model/Product/ReadHandler.php(48):
>   Magento\ConfigurableProduct\Helper\Product\Options\Loader->load(Object(Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Interceptor))\n#1
>   /var/www/vhosts/examplewebsite.com/httpdocs/vendor/magento/framework/EntityManager/Operation/Read/ReadExtensions.php(48):
>   Magento\ConfigurableProduct\Model\Product\ReadHandler->execute(Object(Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Interceptor),
>   Array)\n#2
>   /var/www/vhosts/examplewebsite.com/httpdocs/vendor/magento/framework/EntityManager/Operation/Read.php(112):
>   Magento\Framework\EntityManager\Operation\Read\ReadExtensions->execute(Object(Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Interceptor),
>   Array)\n#3 /var/www/vhosts/exa...\n', referer:

https://www.examplewebsite.com/admin_example/sales/order/index/key/f75ed80b5a5debd27a6c9ee80d52895f1f3f2ff147d6356a12402b56cca00af0/

Can anyone suggest a way to fix this please?

Comment: Can you please share the payment method of the order you've facing issue with? Also, your magento version.

Comment: Thanks for responding. The Magento version is given at the start of the question (2.3.2). I have added the payment method (Visa card through Sagepay PI integration) to the question now.

Comment: Thanks for the info. This issue is occurring for all the orders or any specific order on your website? Have you got any error logs for the same?

Comment: Hi. Just for a single order at the moment and there is an apache error which seems to happen when I try to access the order. I have added the error into the original question.

Comment: OK, please check my answer regarding the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can fix this issue by adding temporary solution adding simple condition in `Magento\ConfigurableProduct\Helper\Product\Options\Loader::load(ProductInterface $product)` after line no : 51

```
if (get_class($typeInstance) == 'Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Type\Simple' || get_class($typeInstance) == 'Magento\Bundle\Model\Product\Type') 
{
   return null;
}
```

> Reference: https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/21663

***Hope it helps!!!***

Comment: THANK YOU!!!

In my case the file in question was located at: 
vendor > magento > module-configurable-product > Helper > Product > Options > Loader.php

But the solution has worked all the same. I'm going to try to work up a custom module so that it doesn't overwrite next time I update but this has definitely got me a lot closer.

Comment: Perfect... Yes overriding the function in your custom module is a best approach.