# Information Changes have been made to this section that have not been saved. This tab contains invalid data in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, error, sales-order, order-status

I am facing this error in the admin side when viewing the orders.

It showing

```
Order View
Information Changes have been made to this section that have not been saved. This tab contains invalid data. Please resolve this before saving.
```

[image]

I am getting this error on that page.

```
<b>Fatal error</b>:  Uncaught Error: Call to a member function getValue()     on null in /home/oherron/public_html/vendor/magento/module-sales/view/adminhtml/templates/order/view/info.phtml:162
```

Comment: Can you please share your code info.phtml

Comment: Hi, I solved that issue in info.phtml. Now it is working.

Comment: oh good to hear.. happy  coding :)

Comment: Can you answer this question? -> https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/300661/credit-card-payment-is-showing-without-even-enabling-it-on-braintree-or-payment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is usually because of an Exception.

Looking at the PHP Logs

```
tail -50f  /var/log/php-fpm/www-error.log
```

I found this error:

```
[11-Jan-2020 04:53:51 UTC] PHP Fatal error:  Method Magento\Ui\TemplateEngine\Xhtml\Result::__toString() must not throw an exception, caught TypeError: Argument 2 passed to Magento\Sales\Model\ResourceModel\Order\Shipment\Relation::__construct() must be an instance of Magento\Sales\Model\ResourceModel\Order\Shipment\Track, instance of YYYY\OrderTrackingUpdate\Sales\Model\ResourceModel\Order\Shipment\Track given, called in /var/www/html/vhosts/sharath/XXXXXXXXXX/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php on line 111 in /var/www/html/vhosts/sharath/XXXXXXXXXX/vendor/magento/module-ui/Component/Wrapper/UiComponent.php on line 0
```

Turns out, in my case, there was a preference in one of my custom module's `di.xml` (that I had overlooked) that was causing the issue.

Once I fixed that - the Order Details pages rendered by just fine.

I hope this helps! :)